# Is it possible to make an array of pointers to struct (node)?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, tree, treenode

So I'm trying to make a prefix tree, but I'm not sure if this would cause some logical error of some sort?

```
typedef struct TreeTag
{
    char letter;
    struct TreeTag *links[26]; /* Is this advisable? */
    int fullword;
    int linknum;
}TreeNode;
```

Comment: It is legal code as `links` is an array of `struct TreeTag*`, not `struct TreeTag` which is not yet defined. It is common for members of `struct`s to be pointers to themselves (think of a linked list).

Comment: Refer to a book on data structures. It ll make things clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, array of pointers to struct node is allowed

If you do this:

```
struct node * p; //it's allowed
```

so there is no problem to declare array of pointers.

When you need the more than one pointers to the same struct you do this

```
struct node * left;
 strcut node * right;
```

so why can't you do this

```
struct node *child[2];
```

Similarly `struct node *p[26]` is also possible but everything depends on your requirement and implementation.

One requirement , As I think think of `d-ary tree` (where each node has d nodes)
And you want to directly nevigate to it's children from parent node.

so `struct node *child[d]` is legal (where d is `#defined` )

Comment: Is it a common practice? or does it seem odd?

Comment: you can make it as per your requirement , but it's not that common

Comment: @vincentbelkin : hope you got it.

Answer (score 0):

That's fine. You can use pointers to the struct inside the struct.

The struct is considered declared, but not defined, at the point you declare the member, and pointers to declared, but not yet defined types, are common. How would you, for example, be able to define the nodes in a binary tree or a linked list otherwise? For a list, you would normally do something like

```
typedef struct ListItem {
   struct ListItem * next;
   SomeType data;
} ListItem;
```